# How to make recursive portals in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I want to make a quite simple portal game in three js but I have a problem with making recursive portals.

I've come up with the idea of placing camera on one portal and rendering its image to texture on the other portal. It works fine, except portals cannot be recursive, because by default WebGL cannot render texture to itself. So when i place the portals one after another and look through one of it i don't see the second. Is there any simple way to avoid this problem?

```
class Portal {
    constructor(source, destination) {
        this.render_target = new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget($(window).width(), $(window).height())
        this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, 1, 0.1, 10000)
        this.camera.position.set(...destination)
        this.object = new THREE.Object3D()
        let materials = new Array(6).fill(0).map(x => new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x0000ff}))
        materials[4] = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: this.render_target.texture })
        this.src_portal = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.BoxGeometry(50, 50, 1), materials)
        this.src_portal.position.set(...source)
        this.object.add(this.src_portal)
        materials = new Array(6).fill(0).map(x => new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x0000ff}))
        materials[5] = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xff0000 })
        this.dst_portal = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.BoxGeometry(50, 50, 1), materials)
        this.dst_portal.position.set(...destination)
        this.object.add(this.dst_portal)
    }
    render(renderer, scene, camera) {
        this.camera.lookAt(this.camera.position.x, this.camera.position.y, this.camera.position.z-1)
        this.camera.applyQuaternion(camera.quaternion)
        renderer.render(scene, this.camera, this.render_target)
    }
}

//main rendering

$(document).ready(function() {
    const scene = new THREE.Scene()
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, $(window).width()/$(window).height(), 0.1, 10000)
    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer()
    renderer.setClearColor(0xffffff)
    renderer.setSize($(window).width(), $(window).height())
    $("#root").append(renderer.domElement)

    camera.position.set(100, 100, 100)
    camera.lookAt(scene.position)

    var orbitControl = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
    orbitControl.addEventListener('change', function () {
        renderer.render(scene, camera)
    });

    let grid = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.PlaneGeometry(1000, 1000, 100, 100), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        side: THREE.DoubleSide, color: 0x000000, wireframe: true
    }))
    grid.rotation.x = Math.PI/2
    scene.add(grid)

    let portal = new Portal([0, 50, 0], [10, 50, 100])
    scene.add(portal.object)

    let materials = new Array(6).fill(0).map(x => new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        color: Math.floor(Math.random()*0xffffff)
    }))

    let box = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.BoxGeometry(50, 50, 50), materials)
    box.position.set(0, 0, -300)
    scene.add(box)

    let frames = 0
    setInterval(() => {
        $("#fps").html("FPS: "+frames)
        frames = 0
    }, 1000);
    render()
    function render() {

        portal.render(renderer, scene.clone(), camera)
        renderer.render(scene, camera)
        requestAnimationFrame(render)
        frames++
    }
})
```

When i try to place the portals to make a loop, it gives me the warning 'GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glDrawArrays: Source and destination textures of the draw are the same.' and the portal is completely invisible inside itself. Is there possible to avoid this or should I make it completely differently?

Comment: Related https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/12033

Answer (score 1):

You have to render the scene to the texture from a different camera and then render the main scene. Looking at your code, you have only one camera and render the scene only once.
It is possible to achieve this effect. There is a good example from Lee Stemkoski that you might wanna look into.

https://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Camera-Texture.html

Code https://github.com/stemkoski/stemkoski.github.com/blob/master/Three.js/Camera-Texture.html

Comment: I have an external scene and camera and call the Portal.render() method inside animation frame function along with rendering main scene

Comment: @SzymonKurowski From your comment I can only see that the main loop calls render once. Maybe provide jsfiddle or atleast the rest of the code?

Comment: Ok thank you for this link, I found the solution in it. The point is to use whole additional scene as an intermediary between the portal and the scene.

Comment: You don't have to use any additional scene... Just render it separately for portal with different camera and render target.